# Current and up to date list of ART runtime compatible apps?

Tags: android, runtime

I'm thinking about changing my Android phone to run the ART runtime mode. Before i do so, i'd like to check what apps are compatible. Is there a current and up to date list of ART runtime compatible apps?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Android apps

Answer (score 0):

ART is backward compatible, using the Dex (Dalvik executable) byte code format. So most apps should just run (and even run better).

Source: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/07/23/will-my-android-app-still-run-with-art-instead-of-dalvik